# Cyclic serialisation with Many to Many relationship with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

I have a parent (Program) pojo with a many-to-many relationship with their children (Subscriber).

The problem is when it serialises a Program, it also serialises the Program's Subscribers, which involves serialising their Programs, which involves serialising their Subscribers, until it has serialised every single Program & Subscriber in the database.

The ERD looks like: Program <-> Subscriber

This means what was a tiny 17KB block of data (json) being returned has become a 6.9MB return. Thus in turn blows out the time to serialise the data and then return it.

Why is my parent returning children returning parents returning children? How can I stop this so I only get the Subscribers for each Program? I'm assuming I've done something wrong with my annotations, perhaps? I would like to maintain a many-to-many relationship but without this deeply nested data retrieval.

(Note: I have prior tried adding as many Lazy annotations I can find just to see if that helps. It doesn't. Perhaps I'm doing that wrong too?)

**Program.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="programs")
public class Program extends Core implements Serializable, Cloneable {
   ...
   @ManyToMany()
   @JoinTable(name="program_subscribers",
         joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="program_uid")},
         inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="subscriber_uid")})
   public Set<Subscriber> getSubscribers() { return subscribers; }
   public void setSubscribers(Set<Subscriber> subscribers) { this.subscribers = subscribers; }
```

**Subscriber.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="subscribers")
public class Subscriber extends Core implements Serializable {
   ...
   @ManyToMany(mappedBy="subscribers")
   public Set<Program> getPrograms() { return programs; }
   public void setPrograms(Set<Program> programs) { this.programs = programs;
```

}

**Implementation**

```
public Collection<Program> list() {
  return new Programs.findAll();
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both Bozho and ponkin are on the right track. I needed to stop serialising the data down the wire but the big problem is I am unable to change the pojo -> toJSON class/method where the serialisation takes place. I was also worried about investing time on the toJSON() method considering I was taking such a performance hit at the point of serialisation I wanted a fix that would occur before I had the data rather than afterwards.

Also due to the nature of the Many-to-Many Bidirectional design I had listed I was always going to have this cyclic programs/subscribers/programs/... problem.

Resolution: (for now atleast) I have removed the Subscriber.getProgram() method and created a finder method on the ProgramDAO which returns the Programs by Subscriber.

```
public List<Program> findBySubscriber(Subscriber subscriber) {
  String hql = "select p " +
     "from Program p " +
     " join p.subscribers s " +
     "where s = :sub"
     ;    

  Query q = getSession().createQuery(hql);
  q.setEntity("sub", subscriber);

  List<Program> l = q.list();
  return l;
}
```

For any CRUD work I think I'm just going to have to loop over Programs.getSubscribers, or write more hql helper methods.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't mention the framework you are using for JSON serialization, so I'll assume JAXB. Anyway, the idea is to make the `Subscriber.getPrograms(..)` transient in some way, so that it's not serialized. Hibernate takes care of these 'loops', but others don't. So:

```
@XmlTransient
@ManyToMany(..)
public Set<Program> getPrograms()...
```

If you use another framework, it may have a different annotation/configuration for specifying transient fields. Like the `transient` keyword.

The other way is to customize your mapper to handle the cycle manually, but this is tedious.

Comment: It's a hand me down project, I'm not 100% what's used for JSON serialisation. I see references to com.sdicons.json.mapper.JSONMapper.SimpleMapperHelper. And we have a method public JSONValue toJSON(Object pojo) throws MapperException {}. (guess it's roll your own serialisation)

Comment: Also if I annotate getPrograms() @XmlTransient this would mean I could never have subscriber programs returned?

Comment: yes. The other was is to customize your mapper to take care of the cycle manually.

Answer (score 1):

1) How does "your" serialization work. I mean is it JAXB or custom serialization or smth else.
2) Almost all frameworks let you set the depth of serialization. I mean you can set for example depth in 2. 
3) I advice you not to serialize object with children, mark them(childre) transient, and serialize separately.

Answer (score 1):

How about using annotations? http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.com/2010/08/json-and-cyclical-references.html

Answer (score 0):

From lombok library. Or override equals and hashcode. Use inside hashcode only unique fields (e.g. id).

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false, of = {"id"})
```